# VPN Service Blocks Incoming Connections

Tags: vpn

I have a subscription to NordVPN. I like them well enough, however they seem to be blocking incoming connections. What I would like to do is host my own VPN so I can connect back into my house securely, whilst also routing traffic through NordVPN (or another service if so suggested). I know I have the routing done right. So it's a matter of finding a solution to the VPN service blocking incoming connections.

Any input?

Comment: turn off the firewall, nordvpn already has its traffic behind the firewall

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't VPN blocking incoming connections, but rather, for this type of VPN usage, traffics of most, if not all, destinations will be routed to the VPN tunnel (as that was the point), including the ones that are replying the the incoming connections, which prevents the replies from reaching or being recognized (because of NAT) by the recipients.

There are different approaches to workaround it (whether it is possible / sensical depends on various factors):

- bind the servers to another interface (the IP of it) and do source-based routing
- route only or avoid routing traffics to specific destinations into the VPN tunnel
- app-based routing
- other better or worse approaches that I couldn't think of